# Nginx default configuration directory

Tags: linux, git, macos, nginx, server

I would like to manage my nginx configs in a git repo for multiple different websites. I develop on OSX and deploy to Ubuntu boxes.

On OSX, after installing with `brew` my nginx default/root directory is `/usr/local/etc/nginx`. To start nginx on the command line, I simply run `nginx` which looks in the default/root directory `/usr/local/etc/nginx`. How can I change this when starting nginx to run nginx configuration from a directory I specify?

Comment: I realize there is a workaround to this by using symlinks. I'm curious for different ways to accomplish this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can specify the configuration file to run Nginx with using the -c option.

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Any includes in your Nginx config that are relative will be relative to that config file specified, so that can allow you to use a different set of configs.